# Input Sanitising Laravel 4

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, rest, laravel

I am using Laravel 4 to create a RESTful interface for my AngularJS app.

At the moment, I want to update an object. My model is called `Discount Link` The way I do this is:

```
    $data = Input::all();
    $affectedRows = DiscountLink::where('id', '=', $id)->update($data);
```

(Please imagine there are some kind of validation checks)

I get an error in my `laravel.log`:

```
General error: 1 no such column: $edit
```

Edit is a value that was passed to my server because it was added in by angular. I don't see the need to explicitly remove this in my JS so my question is:

How can I create some kind of whitelist of key-names that my model will pay attention to. That way, even if something get's passed in by accident, the REST call doesn't have to fail.

I guess there are arguments for sanitising in the JS but i will then pollute my code with many de-assignment statements which could become messy, especially when dealing with AngularJS:

```
delete discountLink.$edit;
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

```
$data = Input::all();
$discountLink = DiscountLink::find($id);
$discountLink->fill($data);
$discountLink->save();
```

This method is working. But your fillable/guarded attribute must be set correct.

UPDATE:

New method:

```
$data = Input::all();
$data['id'] = $id;
$genre = new Genre;
$genre->exists = true;
$genre->update($data);
```

It's 1 query, as I know.

Comment: What is the need here to first retrieve the object? Is there any way to do this without the extra DB call?

Comment: Hmm... I'll think about this, but I think -- no. Ask this on laravel.io, I'm interested in question too.

Comment: Also you can write class, which extends eloquent model, and add this feature to this class. And extends your all model from this new class.

But ask on laravel.io is better)

Comment: What is `$genre->exists` for?

Comment: https://github.com/illuminate/database/blob/master/Eloquent/Model.php

This is attribute which indicate if model exists in database. If you try to do update with exists = false, then Eloquent will try to create this model. But database doesn't allow this, because you already have item with this ID.

But if you really know that database have this ID, you can change this property manually. Also this attribute is public, so I think developers of laravel provided this opportunity.